# Docker React App not updating changes to react app when code is edited

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, create-react-app

So I've been tinkering with Docker and I cannot seem to get the container to update when the client code is updated. I've looked at related articles on adding environment to the component with CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING and the WATCHPACK_POLLING but those do not seem to work for me. I have to completely prune docker and up again for the changes to show.

My projects setup in folder structure is like the following

- root

  - docker-compose.yml
  - services/

    - client
      Dockerfile
    - Server
      Dockerfile

The client is create-react-app base install, and the server is a nest js base install.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - local
    volumes: 
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: 
      context: ./services/api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - local
    volumes:
      - './api:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
  client:
    container_name: client
    stdin_open: true
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./services/client
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - local
    volumes:
      - './client:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'

networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
    driver: local
```

My client Dockerfile is the following

```
FROM node:latest
 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./ 

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001
 
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Another odd piece is when i docker-compose up -d it create two new folders at the root level labelled server/ and then one for client/ both with a blank ./node_modules folder.

Is someone able to help me get the docker to register when a change is made in code to display that via the website without restarting and deleting docker? Also if this makes a difference I am using a macbook pro i9 chip so I am not using the WSL for windows.

I've tried doing different types of dockerfiles, different node bases and also adding the environment variables typically used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be incorrectly mounting directory. According to Dockerfile the bind mount for service client should be

```
volumes:
  - './client:/usr/src/app'
```

For debugging you can check if your made changes are being reflected inside the client container:

```
docker compose exec -it client bash
```